# When nesting in JS-"while loop" variable is not defined anymore

Tags: javascript, while-loop, indexeddb

My JS-script checks, if the database has values. if it does not it fills the database. When triggered again the values from the database are displayed on the page. This works when I run te script twice by reloading the page. When I but the whole thing in a while loop it does not work at all. The loop runs forever because I guess it cannot enter the `marmaInfo.onsuccess = function(evt) {`
I'm not sure if it is a scope problem, i just cant figure it out, why it behaves differently when the while loop is active.

```
var key = $('#marmaID').val();
console.log("key " + key );
store = getObjectStore("marmasStore", 'readwrite');

let i = 0;
//while (i < 1) {
    var marmaInfo = store.get(key);
    marmaInfo.onsuccess = function(evt) {
        var req = store.openCursor(key);
        var record = evt.target.result;
        console.log("record:", record);
        req.onsuccess = function(e) {
          var cursor = e.target.result; 
          if (cursor !== null) { // key already exist
            console.log(key + " FOUND");
            console.log("load and display values of " + key);
            data = marmaInfo.result
            //build page
            // Marma information
            document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML = data.sanskrit;
            console.log("display values of " + key + " DONE");
            i++;
          } else { // key not exist
            console.log(key + " NOT FOUND");
            console.log("initial filling DB ...");
            initialMarmaData.forEach((marma) => {
                var request = store.put(marma);
                request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                    console.log(event.target.result + " initial filling DB DONE");
                };
            //return;
            });
            //store.add(obj)
          }
        };
    };
    marmaInfo.onerror = function(evt) {
        console.log("error");
        i++;    
    }
//}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with such a loop?  That loop contains exactly 3 "lines of code" (3 operations).  (1) It fetches from the store.  (2-3) It assigns event handlers to what it fetches.  And it just repeats these two operations infinitely, since neither of them modify the value of `i`.  Did you mean to put a loop *inside* the event handler instead?  (Or inside the event handler that gets assigned within that first event handler?)

Comment: Remember that the `onsuccess` and `onerror` callback functions execute asynchronously, not while the loop is executing.

Comment: I think what you want is recursion, not a loop. Put the code in a named function. Then the `onerror` callback can call it again to retry.

Comment: @David thanks for your answer. Basically just the most inner if statement needs to loop. I check if the key exsists. If it does, do some operation and setting i=1. If it does not, create the key and run the if statment again. then the key exists and the operations should be performed. But I need alle the operations before the if statement, to look up the key again. That last part does not work.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! recursion was the solution. I postet my updated code below.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar had the right idea, it works with recursion. Thanks alot @Barmar

This is the code with recursion:

```
let i = null;
function recurse() {
    i++;
    console.log("loop " + i);
    var key = $('#marmaID').val();
    console.log("key " + key );
    store = getObjectStore("marmasStore", 'readwrite');
        var marmaInfo = store.get(key);
        marmaInfo.onsuccess = function(evt) {
            var req = store.openCursor(key);
            var record = evt.target.result;
            req.onsuccess = function(e) {
                var cursor = e.target.result; 
                  if (cursor !== null) { // key already exist
                    console.log(key + " FOUND");
                    data = marmaInfo.result
                    //build page
                    document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML = data.sanskrit;
                    console.log("display values of " + key + " DONE");
                  } else { // key not exist
                    console.log(key + " NOT FOUND");
                    console.log("initial filling DB ...");
                    initialMarmaData.forEach((marma) => {
                        var request = store.put(marma);
                        request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                            console.log(event.target.result + " initial filling DB DONE");
                        };
                    });
                      if (i > 2) {
                        return;//this is just for savety
                      }
                    recurse()
                  }
            };
        };
        marmaInfo.onerror = function(evt) {
            console.log("error");
            return; 
        }
};
//}
recurse()
```